# Is progress in the coop campaign in Portal 2 saved?

Tags: portal-2

I've started playing the coop campaign of Portal 2 during launch break today, and had to stop because of time constraint. I didn't find an option to save the game, so we just disconnected.

Is there a way to save the coop campaign progression? If yes, how does it work? Or will I have to play the whole campaign in a single play session?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, the progress is automatically saved and synced to the Steam Cloud individually - so when you next join a co-op game it will have stored which levels you have completed. This also means that your progress is shared across any computer you play Portal 2 on.

It's worth noting that progress is never saved during a test chamber though, only upon successful completion.

You will be able to pick which level to start at next time you start the game - if you go to the specific chapter you want to play and use the buttons until you've selected the level you want, then go into the assembly machine as usual.

Comment: I just completed the last test of a level and it doesn't mark the progress and doesn't let me go to the next. Creating a new game doesn't fix this for me, I'll try to restart Portal 2 and let you know if it does...

Comment: Restarting the game and completing the test again seemed to have fixed my problem.

Comment: @TomWij: I did just have some issues when starting a new co-op session - it threw us in the hub but with no progress at all, so it was impossible to do anything. Restarting fixed it so I guess it's just teething issues perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I guess the server was having problems for a moment in time, hope it doesn't occur more frequent...

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing split-screen co-op on the one computer, then your progress is not saved. Instead, all levels are open to you so you can just go straight to the last level you completed.

Answer (score -4):

No because when I went back on coop portal 2 I started from the begining

Comment: Please be more specific about this.